# Fetching environment variables — can I use pattern matching?

Tags: functional-programming, error-handling, elixir

I've got the following Elixir code:

```
defmodule Envvar do
    def exists?(env) do :os.getenv(env) != false end

    def get(env) do 
        if exists?(env) do
            {env, :os.getenv(env)}
        else 
            {env, nil}
        end 
    end
end
```

Two things:

1. Am I using the `?` correctly here?  I'm assuming that any predicate function should have the `?` on the end of the name by convention.
2. Is there a way to code the *get* function as a pattern match rather than a `if`/`else`?  I'm asking here because I'm guessing that a pattern match would be more idiomatic Elixir code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the ? for a boolean predicate is fine. At least it is what I would do in
Ruby and Elixir.

You won't be able to call exists?(env) in a guard clause so pattern matching does not win you much here.

You are calling :os.getenv() twice unneccessarily. 
I'm not sure why you just want to convert 'false' to 'nil', here is a way:

```
defmodule Envvar do
  def get(env)
    do_get(:os.getenv(env))
  end

  defp do_get(false)
    {:env, nil}
  end

  defp do_get(result)
    {:env,result}
  end
end
```

Comment: That's an interesting take on the pattern matching that I was looking for.  Definitely seems a bit more idiomatic to me.

Comment: By the way, I want the exists? function as a separate function--I would have done a _defp_ if I didn't want to expose it outside of the module.  So I'm not really calling :os.getenv() twice unnecessarily.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci - actually in this solution calling `get` _without_ calling `exists?` will call `:os.getenv()` _less_ than with calling `exists?`. No matter if `env` exists or not - `:os.getenv()` is called exactly once.

Answer (score 3):

Is it necessary to return nil or is false enough? They both evaluate to false when using boolean operators.

If false is good enough:

```
defmodule Envvar do
  def get(env) do
    {:env, :os.getenv(env)}
  end
end
```

If the return value has to be nil, I would just convert the second element and leave the first one intact.

```
defmodule Envvar do
  def get(env) do
    {:env, false_to_nil(:os.getenv(env)) }
  end

  defp false_to_nil(false) do
    nil
  end

  defp false_to_nil(v) do
    v
  end
end
```